# Flask web application deployment in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

[So when i run the application in amazon instance it tries to get the data from google inthis image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBvzu.png)

[when it goes to the callback this is the output i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlmYt.png)

I have run an python application with google Oauth2 and ran it successfully locally. Gunicorn serves http and google Oauth2 requires hhtps. I locally used certificates i have generated and it worked successfully, but when i try to deploy in Amazon Ec2 instance, it doesn't work. Did anyone face such kind of problem?  will using nginx be helpfull in that case?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? We need more details. Using nginx will just add more parts in the chain that can stop working. I'd verify it works as a simple WSGI app first, only then with gunicorn, nginx or other WSGI supporting web servers.

Comment: @advance512 it works as a simple WSGI and also with gunicorn locally, but when i deploy it in amazon instance and try to login with google , it doesnt work. if you are not able to get an idea, i will once again run the application and get the screenshot and get back to you

Comment: It seems like you problem is with OAuth2, and that is a hell of a problem - there could be thousands of issues with this complex and horrible system. (Interesting read: https://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/) I would say that your best would be to add logs and see what works and when exactly it breaks, if you get an idea of what exactly fails, maybe we can help and solve it. Quick bet: the issues are the redirection URLs.

Comment: @advance512  i have added the images when i ran on amazon instance with this command gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app
and when i use this command gunicorn -w3 --certfile=ssl.crt --keyfile=ssl.key --bind  0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app ,it doesnt even load the website

Comment: Remember that you have to open the port for the EC2 instance via security groups... there are tons of things that can go awry. I'd look for professional help, or at least for step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: @advance512 okay. thanks for the help. i will do more research on this. if i do know the problem, i will swing back here .